# getContext from another activity to display GridView

Tags: android

I am trying to add a gridview inside a framgment.
 this is the code that have error in Display.java

```
        53-GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        54-
        55-gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Tab1Fragment.getContext(null)));
```

I guess the error is because I need to add context of other activity.

Tab1Fragment.java:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment  {
    private static Context mContext;

    public Tab1Fragment(Context c)
    {  
       mContext = c; 
    } 

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_view, container, false);

        return V;
    }

public static Context getContext(Context c) {
    c = mContext;
    return c;
  }
}
```

this is the error:

```
05-14 18:33:34.752: E/AndroidRuntime(28061):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 18:33:34.752: E/AndroidRuntime(28061): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 18:33:34.752: E/AndroidRuntime(28061):    at com.example.sqlfirst.Display.onCreate(Display.java:55)
05-14 18:33:34.752: E/AndroidRuntime(28061):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
05-14 18:33:34.752: E/AndroidRuntime(28061):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-14 18:33:34.752: E/AndroidRuntime(28061):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
```

Comment: you shouldn't do that. But if you assign null to an object and then you return that object, why do you expect a value != null?

Comment: @Blackbelt well I know its logicly wrong but the null was sugested by eclipse.. but either way I know I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tab1Fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext()` in

```
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Tab1Fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
```

... once the fragment is attached to an activity.

So check `Tab1Fragment.getActivity()` is `null` first.

Comment: You mean I should do it like this   gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Tab1Fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
?

Comment: Yes, instead of `gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Tab1Fragment.getContext(null)));` - and check that `Tab1Fragment.getActivity()` is not null before.

Comment: Sorry, you have to use the `Tab1Fragment` _instance_, of course - no the class. Did you mention it in the question  .... ?

Comment: yes I did add the class .. shuld i add only add instance.getactivty()?

Comment: As you are inside of the fragment `this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()` should work.

Comment: Okay i will try it then ill get back to you .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not bind Application context with Views, it makes garbage collection difficult because application context will not allow dead objects to be garbage collection. I think the fragment inside which you are adding your grid view,
Suppose

Activity A

Fragment which will hold grid view F

A --> F --->Grid View

Then `F.getActivity()` is good enough to do the job.

Comment: uhmm do you know or have an example for grid views inside fragment tab so I can improve my code?

Comment: @Moudiz here you go... http://www.perfectapk.com/android-gridview-viewholder.html